# Quelle expression utiliser lorsqu'on résout un tel système d'équations ?

Tags: expressions, mathématiques

Supposant que j'ai une équation

```
x=2          [1]    
2xy + x = 0  [2]
```

et donc en « utilisant » [1] dans [2]:

```
y= -1/2
```

Est-ce qu'on « insère » l'équation [1] dans l'équation [2] ? Quelle est l'expression employée en français ?

Comment: Un peu de lecture supplémentaire sur la substitution : ["Méthode par substitution" - Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_d%27%C3%A9quations_%28math%C3%A9matiques_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaires%29#M.C3.A9thode_par_substitution), [Mathematiquesfaciles.com](http://www.mathematiquesfaciles.com/resolution-par-substitution_2_100260.htm). Les deux pages parlent aussi de **remplacer** une variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words I heard a lot during my studies are "*injecter*" and "*substituer*".

[Here's an example of words that can be used](http://mathocollege.free.fr/brevet/sysequ/sysequ.html).

In your example, your first equation is a single variable. When the equation is reduced to that, you can use "*remplacer*" (*remplacer une variable par sa valeur*) or "*injecter*" (*injecter une équation dans une autre*).

When you have more complex equations, still with unknowns, you can still use "*injecter*", and "*substituer*" (*substituer une variable dans une équation d'après une autre équation*).

I believe the words are pretty transparent.

"*On injecte l'équation [1] dans l'équation [2]*" seems ok to me.

Comment: This is the one I would use. Not only it is mathematically correct, but it's also a lot more accurate for describing the method you're using.

Comment: @Lambie Merci d'avoir downvote tout le monde. Je peux t'assurer qu'insérer ou injecter une équation dans une autre ne choque personne, au mieux c'est correct et au pire c'est une contraction d' "injecter le résultat de l'équation". Mais bon quand des profs l'utilisent j'imagine que c'est admis de l'utiliser aussi, après je sais pas ou t'as étudié.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat C'est curieux que pour une formulation si évidente selon vous, on ne trouve que trois occurrences sur google à site:.fr. En tout cas, on anglais, on ne dit pas insert one equation in another puisque /insertion [en anglais] n'est pas un calcule mathématique.

Comment: guillaume a bien répondu à la question. J'ai voté pour sa réponse.

Answer (score 4):

Dans ce cas précis, je dirais : *on remplace x par sa valeur* (ou *en remplaçant x...*).

Si x avait une forme plus complexe (par exemple, x = 2y + 1), je dirais : *on remplace x par son expression* ou encore *en remplaçant x par son expression en fonction de y*. Ces tournures de phrases sont par exemple employées dans [ce document](http://www.normalesup.org/~dconduche/premieres/controles/controle2B-1c.pdf).

Je n'ai jamais entendu dire qu'on *insérait* une équation dans une autre mais je peux me tromper. Si quelqu'un propose une meilleure réponse, j'effacerai celle-là.

Comment: @Lambie Certainement, mais dans ce cas précis, j'utiliserais sans aucune hésitation _remplacer_, peu m'importe le terme anglais. Pour des équations plus complexes, le _combiner_ de Guillaume me paraît convenir, ainsi que les solutions proposées par Teleporting Goat.

Answer (score 4):

**combiner**  est le meilleur terme pour

> mélanger deux équations, afin de les simplifier, ou réduire le nombre
>   d'inconnues.

Exemple [sur le site de l'académie de Toulouse](http://pedagogie.ac-toulouse.fr/math/college/eclair/Formation070611/Reynerie%20cours_systeme.pdf).

on peut encore employer:

- mixer
- fusionner

On emploie *insérer* (ou plutôt *substituer*, *remplacer*), pour *définir* la valeur d'une inconnue dans une seconde équation.